# Dynamically get PSCustomObject property and values

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have the following:

```powershell
$test = [pscustomobject]@{
    First = "Donald";
    Middle = "Fauntleroy";
    Last = "Duck";
    Age = 80
}
$test | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | % {"$($_.Name)="}
```

which prints:

> ```powershell
> Age=
> First=
> Last=
> Middle=
> ```

I would like to extract the value from each property and have it included as the value for my name value pairs so it would look like:

> ```powershell
> Age=80
> First=Donald
> Last=Duck
> Middle=Fauntleroy
> ```

I am trying to build a string and do not know the property names ahead of time. How do I pull the values to complete my name value pairs?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The only way I could find (so far) is to do something like:

```powershell
$test = [pscustomobject]@{
    First = "Donald";
    Middle = "Fauntleroy";
    Last = "Duck";
    Age = 80
}

$props = Get-Member -InputObject $test -MemberType NoteProperty

foreach($prop in $props) {
    $propValue = $test | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $prop.Name
    $prop.Name + "=" + $propValue
}
```

The key is using `-ExpandProperty`.

Comment: Slight improvement to the value lookup: `$prop.Name + "=" + $test.($prop.Name)`

Comment: @scobi Ironic that I needed this 2 year old thread the same day you posted this!  Your way is very succinct and a good answer to the question.  I would move it to an answer!

Answer (score 10):

Shorter, more PowerShell'ish option:

```powershell
$test | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | % Name | %{
    $_ + '=' + $test.$_
}
```

Comment: `$test.($_.Name)` also works so you can take out `| % Name`

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it is really better, but here's one more variant:

```powershell
$test.psobject.Members | ? {$_.Membertype -eq "noteproperty"} | 
    %{ $_.Name + '='+  $_.Value }
```

Answer (score 2):

My variant:

```powershell
$memberNames = ($test | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty).Name
foreach ($mname in $memberNames) {
    "{0}={1}" -f $mname,$Test."$mname"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way for this old problem.
You can use:

```
$test.PSObject.Properties | %{Write-Output "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)"}
```

If you want to access some field programmatically in runtime, by using variable as a field selector, then you can use:

```
$myProperty = "Age"
$test.PSObject.Properties[$myProperty].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
$MyObjectProperties = Get-Member -InputObject $MyObject -MemberType NoteProperty

$MyObjectProperties | % {
    $PropertyName = $_.Name
    $PropertyValue = $MyObject."$PropertyName"
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't format as requested it does allow for additional processing and doesn't require additional variables.

```
$Test.psobject.members `
| Where-Object MemberType -EQ 'NoteProperty' `
| Select-Object name,value
```

Output:

```
Name    Value
----    -----
Age     80
First   Donald
Last    Duck
Middle  Fauntleroy
```

To achieve requested formatting

```
$Test.psobject.members `
| Where-Object MemberType -EQ 'NoteProperty' `
| Foreach-Object {
    "$($_.name) = $($_.value)"
}
```

Output:

```
Age=80
First=Donald
Last=Duck
Middle=Fauntleroy
```